# Unable to read an MS Access Table (linked to an ODBC Data Source) using PHP

Tags: php, database, windows, ms-access, odbc

I am working on an application in which the data from an ODBC enabled Data Source is imported to an MS Access 2007 Database using a Linked Table. The tricky part is that every time a Link Refresh is made (or the linked table is opened) the ODBC Data Source prompts out a Window where 4 different parameters (username, password, servername, workgroupname) have to be input.

While this is possible manually, I find no way to read this linked Table programatically.

I am using a PHP Script to read the linked table. The Execution of PHP Script is halted indefinitely when I try to read this linked table. My DSN is properly configured and can successfully read the data in all other cases including those linked tables in which the data source doesnot require any input parameters/credentials. However, it fails in this case.

In a nutshell, my system is **PHP**<-->M**S Access (Linked Table)**<--**ODBC Data Source**. The PHP Script aims to read the updated data from the ODBC Data Source using the Linked Table. For some reasons, PHP cannot directly interface with the ODBC Data Source, so I am using MS Access as an intermediary.

The [odbc_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) function of PHP allows only DSN Name, username, password, cursor_type as parameters. I am not sure how do I input the 4 parameters (username, password, servername, workgroupname) as required by the ODBC Data Source to which my MS Access table is linked.

I am using PHP 5.4 on Windows 7 with MS Access 2007.

I request the developer community to help me with necessary pointers on this. Any suggestions for Workaround is also welcome.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: maybe you can try to use workgroup/domain with username eg. *workgroup\name* *name@workgroup* ... what is the error while trying to connect via odbc?

Comment: where is your odbc linked tables come from? SQL server?

Comment: @donald123 I will try this format. No error is displayed. The PHP execution halts and the page load cursor keeps on revolving indefinitely in the browser.

Comment: @krish. It is a proprietary system made by Honeywell which supports only MS Access ODBC drivers.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using double ODBC:  PHP > ODBC > MS ACCESS > ODBC > SOURCE.. you have following options.

- Cut off the "Access" middle man and connect directly.
- if you want to use MS Access, use "FILE DNS" to connect to the linked tables from MS ACCESS where file DNS has all 4 parameters initialized. (This will eliminate MS Access asking you to enter the server information when refreshing linked tables)
- Haven't tried this from PHP side but you can loop through the msysobjects table or database.tabledefinitions and update the link with your custom connection string.

Any way, the solution for your trouble would be. Make Access not to prompt for parameters when refreshing linked tables by either using file dns or save passwords.

Comment: I was using System DNS always. I will try using File DNS. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Connect directly to the data source where linked table derives. If that is MS Access, SQL Server, MySQL, etc. use the appropriate, installed ODBC driver for that particular database.

Here is a PHP/MS Access DSN-less solution using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php).

Also, see [different connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-access-accdb-odbc-driver/) which includes workgroup, user, and password parameters.

```
<?php

$database="C:\Path\To\database.accdb";

# open the connection
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
                    DBq=$database;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";    
    $STH = $dbh->query($sql);

    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit;
}

echo "\n";
while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    # output query results            
    echo $row;
}

# close the connection
$dbh = null;

?>
```

Comment: The problem is that the parent datasource is a proprietary system made by Honeywell, which supports only MS Access ODBC drivers. I cannot directly access it using PHP. Anyway, I will try the connection strings with workgroup you pointed to. Thanks for it.

Comment: Forgive me but the above code does use an MS Access ODBC driver (see red text of connection string). In fact, it models same connection string from the link. Please note this connection string is not limited to PHP. You can use it in Python, R, and even VBA. Only syntax of objects differ among languages.